# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Удобная, детально проработанная и проверенная временем, схема взаимодействия..."
Нужна ли запятая после слова временем?

Answer (score 1):

Нормально - нет, не нужна. Она была бы необходима, если "детально проработанная и проверенная временем" раскрывало бы смысл "удобная", но это явное не так.

Здесь даже интонационную запятую не поставишь, исказит смысл.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу согласиться. Это распространённое определение можно обособить, т. к. оно имеет дополнительное обстоятельственное значение (скорее всего причинное, предложение не окончено, поэтому трудно судить).

Comment: Можете предложить хоть один разумный вариант "окончания" дабы обстоятельственное значение проявилось? Я его не вижу - почему и сказал, что исказится смысл. 

С чем согласен на все сто, так это с тем, что нельзя в таком вопросе фразу недоговаривать. Но уже устал просто доказывать, всё равно будут обрывать на самом интересном месте.

Comment: Я бы тоже запятую в таком предложении не поставила. А обстоятельственное значение можно предположить. Только уступительное. Например, "Удобная, детально проработанная и проверенная временем, схема взаимодействия в этот раз не сработала". Интересно,что с чем там взаимодоействовало?

Comment: Так я говорю: МОЖНО обособить. А значение  однозначно не причинное, это я поторопилась. А давайте договоримся: не даём ответ, пока не закончат фразу.

Comment: Удобная, детально проработанная и проверенная временем схема взаимодействия на всех этапах сотрудничества.

Прошу прощения, в следующий раз фразу обрывать не буду. Эта фраза приводится в рекламе о компании. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна. Классический случай - определяемое слово стоит после определения, добавочное обстоятельственное значение отсутствует.